# Reprojecting swath to lat lon grid?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, proj

I have satellite swath data in the form of an HDF5 file containing 3 arrays: 'data_array', 'latitude' and 'longitude'.
All three are 32-bit floats, are arrays of the same dimensions (X-by-Y) and the names are self-explanatory. All three datasets use a fill value of -32767

What I want to do it reproject data_array from native satellite swath onto a latitude/longitude grid with a pixel size of 0.009 degrees. I want to save the resulting data array as a geoTIFF containing project information (for use in QGis/ENVI/etc).

I have tried using gdal based upon [this](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-November/022680.html) but gdalwarp segfaults (maybe because there are some fill value pixels in the lat/lon grid? Unsure how to deal with this).

I also tried using python and the pytroll libraries, but find the documentation somewhat impenetrable. All my attempts thus far have failed.

So, can anyone recommend a simple method to perform this reprojection?

I assumed it would be something quite common, but am having difficulty finding a solution.

I *can* plot project the data onto a grid using NASA Panoply, but this appears to be for visualisation only. I can't see how to save a GEOTiff output.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question and something is making me wonder : if you have lat/long value arrays... why would you want to **reproject** the data ? From what I understand, the data is already in lat long. no ? To help us understand, maybe you could try and upload some data, some extract of data or at least some header file content ?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154959/strange-effect-in-gdalwarp-output

Comment: it would help to know what data you are using. Is it MODIS data ? other NASA data ?

Comment: @gisnside The data is in raw instrument swath projection, which is unsuited for merging with other data sources. Hence why I wish to reproject onto a lat/lon grid.

Comment: @AndreJ, yes - i saw both of those topics before posting my own question. I can't really figure out how they are of use, though.

Comment: @radouxju The data is not from a publicly available source such as NASA. It's a privately-operated satellite, unfortunately, meaning that I cannot post a sample.

Comment: @os1 could you at least mention which satellite ? It might help :)

Comment: @gisnside The satellite is of no relevance, reprojecting swath data onto a lat/lon grid is (or at least should be) generic.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested by the  **Orfeo Toolbox** which might have some useful feature for you (i only know about the tool, not the detailed procedure).

> Orfeo ToolBox (OTB) is an open-source project for state-of-the-art
>   remote sensing. Built on the shoulders of the open-source geospatial
>   community, it can process high resolution optical, multispectral and
>   radar images at the terabyte scale. A wide variety of applications are
>   available: from ortho-rectification or pansharpening, all the way to
>   classification, SAR processing, and much more!
>
> All of OTB’s algorithms are accessible from Monteverdi, QGIS, Python,
>   the command line or C++. Monteverdi is an easy to use visualization
>   tool with an emphasis on hardware accelerated rendering for high
>   resolution imagery (optical and SAR). With it, end-users can visualize
>   huge raw imagery products and access all of the applications in the
>   toolbox. From resource limited laptops to high performance MPI
>   clusters, OTB is available on Windows, Linux and Mac. It is community
>   driven, extensible and heavily documented.

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/features-2/

You say in one of your comment : *"the data is in raw instrument swath projection"*. You might specifically be interested by the [Orfeo Toolbox recipes](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Recipes.html) structured in articles and with code examples :

**[From raw image to calibrated product](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/optpreproc.html)**

> **Pre-processing tasks**
>
> This section presents various pre-processing tasks that are presented
>   in a classical order to obtain a calibrated, pan-sharpened image.
>
> - Optical radiometric calibration
> - Pan-sharpening
> - Digital Elevation Model management
> - Ortho-rectification and map projections

In the same area, one more page should help you out :

**[Residual registration](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/residual_registration.html)**

> Image registration is a fundamental problem in image processing. The
>   aim is to align two or more images of the same scene often taken at
>   different times, from different viewpoints, or by different sensors.
>   It is a basic step for orthorectification, image stitching, image
>   fusion, change detection, and others.
>   [...]
>   Sensor model is generally not sufficient to provide image
>   registrations. Indeed, several sources of geometric distortion can be
>   contained in optical remote sensing images including earth rotation,
>   platform movement, non linearity, etc.
>
> They result in geometric errors on scene level, image level and pixel
>   level. It is critical to rectify the errors before a thematic map is
>   generated, especially when the remote sensing data need to be
>   integrated together with other GIS data.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate this and see if it is helpful, if so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: No problem. I regret it's not more detailed but I have limited knowledge on image preprocessing like this. I have more knowledge on the image classification side, when the image has been pre-processed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try georeferencing through thinplate spline (tps).

In Python should it be something like this code line:

```
import gdal
FOLD = 'C:/FOLD'
img1=gdal.Open(FOLD+"/Imagery.hdf5")
img2=gdal.Open(img1.GetSubDatasets()[3][0]) #where 3 is the band of interest (is an example)
gdal.Warp(FOLD+'/FILE.tif',img2,tps=True) #the -tps algorithm georreferences your data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GDAL:

```
gdal_translate hdf5_file -sds bands.tif
```

Or this in R:

```
library(gdalUtils)
band=1
file_path<-"/myfolder/myfile.hdf"
system(paste0('gdal_translate ', get_subdatasets(file_path)[band],' myfile_', band','.tif'))
```